# Visualized javap tool

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-8, javadoc, javap

Hello I've created this [tool](http://javap.taichiswag.in)
And I've added a feature that anyone can search for the info of a class without any package name.
My question is now I want to add info of each method that means I need to get info from javadoc html files so tell me  I parse all html cause I don't want to embed the whole html I want certain texts

Comment: The entry point into a Javadoc's class documentation can be constructed using the root URL (e.g. file:///extra/JDK8u20/jdk1.8.0_20/docs/api) followed by the package and class and .html. So why don't you simply link to this?

Comment: When you start a sentence with “My question is …”, it’s a good idea to let follow an actual question or at least an actual sentence instead of over forty words without any point nor comma. The closest thing that we can assume to be intended a question is “so tell me I parse all html”, but it’s meaning remains unclear.

Comment: Simply I want to do Suppose someone searched for "String" class on my tool as mentioned above or attaching URL too.  then all details of string class will be showen by tool... Is there any way to map each method with javadoc details only with a particular method.  Have a look http://javap.taichiswag.in